# python dataframe error : cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value

Tags: python

```
df['CRIM'].sort_values()[-10:] = df['CRIM'].sort_values()[-10:-9]
```

I want to change the top 10 values ​​of CRIM to the 10th value of CRIM

but error is cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value
sorry i'm not good in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting a value instead of a slice with `.iloc`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(10)})
print(df)
df["a"][-5:] = df["a"].iloc[-5]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code errors because the slices on either side of the equal side are not equal in length. The slice on the left has length 10, the slice on the right has length 1. So you have one value, that you're trying to set on 10 values. This only works if the one value is a native data type, such as integers or floats.

```
len(df['CRIM'].sort_values()[-10:])
>>> 10
len(df['CRIM'].sort_values()[-10:-9])
>>> 1
```